# Why dosent django find my assets and attachements?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, deployment, centos7

I have a website hosted on centos7 And I want to move it to ubuntu22.04.3 I installed python 3.10.12 and 3.11.4 versions django and all prerequisits I'v changed the apacheconfig file but when I run the server It works but it does not find my assets and attachements here is the output on the stdout:

```
sudo python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 29, 2023 - 12:00:53
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'website.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /fr/ HTTP/1.1" 200 55434
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /assets/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /assets/css/bootstrap-icons.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /uploads/2022/12/08/photo1.PNG HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[29/Aug/2023 12:00:58] "GET /uploads/2023/03/17/image35.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Please any idea might help share if you have a clue

I tried modifying the apache2 config file and a lot more.

Comment: Did you check django docs for static file serving? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/. If you did, can you share your settings too. With this way it is too hard to debug or get idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Side note: it looks like you're using the development web server ([`manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#runserver)). That server is not suitable for real hosting: "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making web frameworks, not web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)" It also live reloads code, which doesn't make sense in a real environment.

Comment: Please check the answers for the configuration Is it suitable to use apache2 instead of the manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

This is the apache2 config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # ServerName domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_production
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ams_siteProduction_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ams_siteProduction_access.log combined

        Alias /assets/ /var/www/html/public_production/assets/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/assets>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /attachments/ /var/www/html/public_production/attachments/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/attachments>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /uploads/ /var/www/html/public_production/uploads/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/uploads>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    
        WSGIDaemonProcess amsSiteProcess python-path=/var/www/site/site_production
        WSGIProcessGroup amsSiteProcess
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site/site_production/ams_site/wsgi.py
    
        <Directory /var/www/site/site_production/ams_site>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:28560>
        # ServerName domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_production
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ams_adminProduction_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ams_adminProduction_access.log combined

        Alias /assets/ /var/www/html/public_production/assets/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/assets>
             Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /attachments/ /var/www/html/public_production/attachments/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/attachments>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /uploads/ /var/www/html/public_production/uploads/
        <Directory /var/www/html/public_production/uploads>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    
        WSGIDaemonProcess amsAdminProcess python-path=/var/www/site/site_production
        WSGIProcessGroup amsAdminProcess
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site/site_production/ams_admin/wsgi.py
    
        <Directory /var/www/site/site_production/ams_admin>
                 <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
                 </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```